# Определение раскладки клавиатуры при создании кейлогера на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура

Пытаюсь сделать простенький кейлогер по примеру. Но проблема в том, что он не определяет когда была изменена раскладка клавиатуры и когда пользователь вводит большие буквы.
Например при запуске программы у пользователя стоял **Русский язык**. Кейлогер считывает нажатие клавиш, но когда пользователь поменял раскладку на **Английский**, то кейлогер продолжает считывать нажатие клавиш как русские буквы.
Я набросал небольшой код, который должен при нажатии клавиши сначала определить какой это язык, а потом выводить букву, но даже так ничего не работает. Нажатие клавиш считывается и язык указывается только тот, который был при запуске программы. Подскажите пожалуйста как определить раскладку клавиату и нажата ли **CapsLock** в ходе выполнения программы.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import ctypes


def get_key_name(key):
    if isinstance(key, keyboard.KeyCode):
        return key.char
    else:
        return str(key)


def on_press(key):
    u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    pf = getattr(u, "GetKeyboardLayout")
    CodeLang = (hex(pf(0)))  # передаем в переменную строковое значение языка
    print(hex(pf(0)))  # выводим раскладку

    # Выводим язык в зависимости от значения lang
    if CodeLang == '0x4090409':
        lang = ('En')
        print(lang)
    if CodeLang == '0x4190419':
        lang = ('Ru')
        print(lang)
    if CodeLang == '-0xf57fbde':
        lang = ('Ua')
        print(lang)

    key_name = get_key_name(key)
    print('Key {} pressed.'.format(key_name))


def on_release(key):
    key_name = get_key_name(key)

    if key_name == 'Key.esc':
        print('Exiting...')
        exit(0)
        return False


with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Поправьте отступы в коде. В данном виде код нерабочий.

Comment: Не в коде дело. Код рабочий. Отступы поставил.

Comment: Код нерабочий, потому что не запускается. Если кто-то скопирует этот код и попытается его запустить, то будет ошибка.

Comment: Посмотрите сейчас

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379713/cant-get-current-keyboard-layout/ похожий только на английском, можете почитать.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение частично.
Определение раскладки клавиатуры в IDE и в PyCharm отлично работает, но когда запускаю файл .py, то все как и было (раскладка не определяется и условия не срабатывают).
В приведенном ниже коде при первом запуске программы происходит определение раскладки клавиатуры. После нажатия на любую клавишу вновь происходит определение раскладки клавиатуры и если раскладка не соответствует той, которая была при запуске программы, то происходит выход из программы. Вот в этом месте (строка 31 вместо exit) нужно как то перезапустить программу, потому что кейлоггер продолжает считывать клавиши на том языке который был определен изначально. Ну или как то решить эту проблему по другому. Как не знаю. Ну и конечно же открыт вопрос почему не работает код при запуске файла .py

```
from pynput import keyboard
from ctypes import *

user32 = windll.user32

# Определяем язык ввода
hwnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
threadID = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, None)
StartLang = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(threadID)
print(StartLang)


def get_key_name(key):
    if isinstance(key, keyboard.KeyCode):
        return key.char
    else:
        return str(key)


def on_press(key):
    # Определяем язык ввода
    hwnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    threadID = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, None)
    CodeLang = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(threadID)
    print(CodeLang)

    if CodeLang == StartLang:
        key_name = get_key_name(key)
        print('Key {} pressed.'.format(key_name))
    else:
        exit()


def on_release(key):
    key_name = get_key_name(key)

    if key_name == 'Key.esc':
        print('Exiting...')
        exit(0)
        return False


with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```